# Make container fit child size

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I was wondering, is there a way to make a `Container` fit his child size instead of expanding to the maximum available space so that it can be used inside a `Wrap` component just like the `Chip` widget?

Cheers!

```dart
Wrap(children: [
  Container(child: Text("austin")),
  Container(child: Text("danger")),
  Container(child: Text("power")),
])
```

Comment: That's the default behavior of `Container`. If it has a child, it'll do exactly that

Comment: A Container is a widget that encapsulates several different widget's function for convenience. If you want yo use specific properties like padding or shape decoration, you can use different widgets, without getting the auto expanding behaviour. What are you trying to achieve, can you share your code?

Comment: @RémiRousselet I thought `Container` would always take the maximum amount of space his parent alows :thinking: But then why it the code (added in my edit) not working. Instead of being wrapped next to each others like `Chips`, they expand and overflow

Comment: It _can_ both have a child and fill its parent, if it has an `alignment`